# Confusion with is.unsorted() function

Tags: r, data.table

When I run those two lines of code, where data is data.table object:

```
data[,is.unsorted(POSIXct, na.rm=T)]
data[,which(diff(POSIXct)<0)]
```

And those are the results I got

```
> data[,is.unsorted(POSIXct, na.rm=T)]
[1] TRUE
> data[,which(diff(POSIXct)<0)]
integer(0)
```

I am confused because if data is unsorted, then shouldn't there be at least one time difference which should be a negative value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the missing values. Check out

```
x <- c(1, NA, 0)
is.unsorted(x, na.rm=TRUE)
# TRUE
which(diff(x)<0)
# integer(0)
```

The `diff` function does pairwise distances, it doesn't skip over missing values. You can see that

```
diff(x)
# [1] NA NA
```

so there are no pairwise values that are less than 0 because they are being compared to NA (and `which` just drops NA values).